# Limit string replacement if match found very near in preg_replace in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a content description and few listed words ("Google" and "Gmail"). Now if these words appear in content description then I have to replace them with their links. I have created a regular expression and replaced them successfully using preg_match. But now I want to limit them. for example:
If 2 found words are very close them this will not be replaced.
My description is as follow:

"This is my description for Google and Gmail. I need to replace Google with its link and also Gmail"

Now my requirement is, First Gmail should not be replaced because first "Google" is very near to it (1 word distance only) and rest of the words should be replaced because the are very far then each other. So my result should be:

```
This is my description for <a href="google.com">Google</a> and Gmail. I need to replace <a href="google.com">Google</a> with its link and also <a href="gmail.com">Gmail</a>.
```

I have used lookahead matching but it is not working.

Comment: How do you quantify "very near" and "very far"? You need to precisely define these in order to determine your solution.

Comment: Replace all the 'Googles-not-followed-by-Gmail' first, then all the Gmails. )

Comment: @nickb Actually, the OP defined it: '1 word distance only'. For example, Google is too close to Gmail in 'Google and Gmail' phrase.

Comment: I’m not sure (only) RegExp are the right tool for this. I think I’d rather find the position of the words in the text first, and than loop over them and calculate the “distance” to other target words, and afterwards base the decision whether to replace them and the results.

Comment: Best bet is to use `preg_match_all()` with `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`

Comment: is there any way so that I can get words around matched string upto 1 or 2 words?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the solution.

I used preg_match_all for each word one by one, then maintained an array of matched words with offset (PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE).

Now I managed a list of all matched words with position and sort that list according to word's weight. Now we can use any algorithm to track nearest replacement in text. I did the following:

```
1: Replace first list word in body and maintain a temp tracking  array with position of this word.
2: For second word in list, first check the temp tracking array and find nearest position of second word. Now you can find words between first word and second word using str_word_count function.
3: Now do this for all words in list.
```